# Why can't serializer fields be optional?

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, serialization

If I have a model serializer where the first_name and last_name are not required in the db model (blank=True, null=True, default=None), and I choose to submit json data that may or may not contain the "first_name" or "last_name" fields, shouldn't those fields exist in validated_data[], regardless if they are not submitted via the json request, as they are listed in the serializer fields and have their default values set to None?

I get a key error if I don't submit "first_name" or "last_name" in the json POST request.

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create method do like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = get_user_model().objects.create(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        first_name=validated_data.get('first_name',''),
        last_name=validated_data.get('last_name','')
    )

    user.save()
    return user
```